# Johnson C++ algorithm compiling error

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm using a code of Jonhson algorithm from https://gist.github.com/ashleyholman/6793360, but when compiling it's throwing me some errors, some of these i've already solved, but there's others that i'm not understanding what can it be... I'll post here, the compiling errors.

33 error: expected expression
43 error: expected expression
85 error: expected expression
103 error: expected expression
105 error: expected expression
159 error: expected ';' at end of declaration

Comment: Compile with flag `-std=c++11`

Comment: Andreas I'm compiling from CodeBlocks

Comment: That work !! Both option, from terminal with the flag and marking that option on CodeBlocks! Thank you. But can you explain me why was I getting that errors? Was it due to c++ compiler version or something like that?

Comment: Compiler version no, but your compiler was building against an older version of the C++ standard. Code::blocks generally ships with a GCC 4.8 compiler which is about 3 years out of date, but is good enough for C++11. Mostly.

Comment: user4581301 thank you. Now I understand what was going on

Answer (score 1):

The code is using `c++11` features such as [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) etc.
 
Compile the code with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` flag.

As you're using codeblocks, here's how:

1. Settings
2. Compiler
3. Compiler Settings
4. Compiler Flags
5. Mark the option `Have g++ follow c++11 standard`
6. Try to compile

Comment: yeah i know, but i've just created this account and have just 9 points, so i can't mark it as accepted for now